# What is an alternative to the words "Enjoy the Show"on a theater program?

Tags: theater

What is an alternative to the words >Enjoy the Showon a theater program?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend ***Turn Off Your Phone***.
It contains more information, and is also more sincere.

Answer (score 1):

**Have a good time**, **let your hair down**,  and **rejoice** may be used on a theater program

Answer (score 0):

These would also work well:

Enjoy. 
  Enjoy! 
  Welcome.